# Angular 2: reference error can't find variable require

Tags: javascript, angular, import, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to include [this](https://github.com/alexguan/node-zookeeper-client) zookeeper's library  in my Angular 2 project. I'm following [this tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps-ff274ba601af), so I created the app, installed the node-zookeeper-client with rpm, and then added `../node_modules/node-zookeeper-client/index.js` to my script array in the .angular-cli.json.

If I start the application, in the console I see an error like `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require` that points to the first line of the index.js file.

Which is the correct approach to import a third party library like zookeeper?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087467/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-require

Comment: did you find any solution for this issue.... im running in the same problem and the declaration of the variable only makes the error more complicated because there are some packages like assertions and net and fs that apparently are needed too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you should solve it if you are using angular cli.
In your

> src/typings.d.ts

paste the below code. It will work like charm

```
declare var require: any;
```

Hope this will help

Comment: It still get error. I already have in index.d.ts  declare var require:NodeRequire, I changed to any but is not working

Comment: `/* SystemJS module definition */
declare var module: NodeModule;
declare var require: any;
interface NodeModule {
  id: string;
}
` Mine looks like this..